# Foundation 5 Abide Normal Submit

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, validation, zurb-foundation

I have an order form that I'm creating. I'm using Codeigniter for the backend and Foundation 5 with Abide Validation and Stripe Checkout for payment. Here's what I'm trying to do:

- user fills out form (abide live validates)
- user submits form
- abide validates
- on valid, open the stripe payment handler
- on successful payment, submit the form

My issue that I'm having is abide is preventing the default form submission. I can do an AJAX post with JQuery, but I'd prefer not to since I can use CSRF with Codeigniter more easily doing a "normal" form submission.

Basically I was hoping for code like below, but it doesn't work because the submit will re-trigger the "valid" event.

```
$('#order_form').on('valid',function(){
    handler.open({ //stripe stuff in here }, function(){
        //if successful payment
        $('#order_form').submit();
    });
});
```

If anyone has some ideas to help, they would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where's the code for the abide validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#order_form').get(0).submit()` will execute the underlying submit without jQuery's bindings.